# Module menu is not displayed in admin panel magento 2

Tags: magento2

menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Ronis_Contactus::contactus" title="Contact us" translate="title" module="Ronis_Contactus" sortOrder="20" dependsOnModule="Ronis_Contactus" resource="Ronis_Contactus::contactus"/>
        <add id="Ronis_Contactus::ronis_contactus" title="Grid" translate="title" module="Ronis_Contactus" sortOrder="10" parent="Ronis_Contactus::contactus" action="contactus" resource="Ronis_Contactus::contactus"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```

acl.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="Ronis_Contactus::contactus" title="Contact us" translate="title" sortOrder="30">
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

Comment: If some answer solved your problem, thanks to accept the answer to help other users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this updated code :

> etc/adminhtml/menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../Backend/etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Ronis_Contactus::contactus" 
             title="Contact us" 
             translate="title"
             module="Ronis_Contactus" 
             sortOrder="20"
             resource="Magento_Backend::content"/>
        <add id="Ronis_Contactus::ronis_contactus" 
             title="Contact us Config" translate="title" 
             module="Ronis_Contactus" 
             sortOrder="10" 
             parent="Ronis_Contactus::contactus" 
             action="adminhtml/system_config/edit/section/contactus" 
             resource="Magento_Backend::content"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```

> etc/acl.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores">
                    <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores_settings">
                        <resource id="Magento_Config::config">
                            <!-- this resource id we can use in system.xml for section -->
                            <resource id="Ronis_Contactus::config" title="Ronis Contactus" sortOrder="30" />
                        </resource>
                    </resource>
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Vendor_ModuleName::first_level_demo"
             title="First Level Item"
             module="Vendor_ModuleName"
             sortOrder="9999"
             resource="Magento_Backend::content" />

        <add id="Vendor_ModuleName::second_level_demo"
             title="Second Level Item"
             module="Vendor_ModuleName"
             sortOrder="0"
             action="menuitem/index/index"
             parent="Vendor_ModuleName::first_level_demo"
             resource="Magento_Backend::content" />
    </menu>
</config>
```

> **Explanation of the directive’s attributes is as follows:**
>
> **id** – unique node identifier, should follow the format: Vendor_Module::menu_item_description
>
> **title** – text that is shown in menu
>
> **module** – current module
>
> **sortOrder** – where to place menu item
>
> **resource** – defines the ACL rule which the admin user must have in order to see and access this menu, it is defined in acl.xml.
>   Otherwise, menu item won’t be rendered. For simplicity,
>   Magento_Backend::content is used.

Answer (score 0):

> app/code/Vendor/Name/etc/adminhtml/menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Ronis_Contactus::contactus_head" title="Contact us" translate="title" module="Ronis_Contactus" sortOrder="20" dependsOnModule="Ronis_Contactus" resource="Ronis_Contactus::contactus_head"/>
        <add id="Ronis_Contactus::ronis_contactus" title="Grid" translate="title" module="Ronis_Contactus" sortOrder="10" parent="Ronis_Contactus::contactus_head" action="contactus" resource="Ronis_Contactus::contactus_child"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Name/etc/acl.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="Ronis_Contactus::contactus_head" title="Contact us" translate="title" sortOrder="30">
                    <resource id="Ronis_Contactus::contactus_child" title="Grid" sortOrder="10" />
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

And finally : `php bin/magento c:f`